# Is there any way to get length of pages in Flutter PageController?

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter and `PageController` for a custom slider with auto-animation of sliding.

The title summarises the question:
I want to find a way to get the total number of pages from the PageController instance.

I can get the current page like this `controller.page` but I see no controller.pages or controller.size

if I have 5 items in the slider i want to fetch the number 5 somehow from the controller

Please focus your answer only on how to do this with PageController instance and not with .length of my array. I am building a mixin so the array is not available but only the pagecontroller is

Comment: I do not think  `PageController` itself provide information about the total number of pages. However, you can pass the total number of pages to your mixin as a separate parameter when initializing it. This can be one way.

Comment: just pass the length as additional parameter :)

Comment: @OMiShah its not an option, it is a complicated scheme using mixin